# print shape values for all dimesions for a given input to a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a simple Keras model -

```
def print_tensor_shape(x):
    print(x.shape)
    return x

def stem(stem_width=32):
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, None, 3])
    X = keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(inputs)
    X = keras.layers.Conv2D(stem_width, kernel_size = 3, strides = 2, activation='relu')(X)
    keras.layers.Lambda(print_tensor_shape)(X)
    return keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=X)
```

I want to view the exact shape of the tensor for a specific input tensor after the convolution layer. However when I run -

```
inputs = tf.zeros([32,512,512,3])
out = stem()(inputs)
```

The output I get is

```
(None, None, None, 32)
```

I want to know the exact values for the first 3 dimensions for the input of shape `[32,512,512,3]` and not just `[None, None, None]`.  Anyone can please help me to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the print output you see (None, None, None, 32) isn't related to the input you passed. it refers generally to the layer dimension. if you would like to check the print you required, take care to connect the Lambda layer in your model. this enables to call the function every time you pass a new input

```
def print_tensor_shape(x):
    print(x.shape)
    return x

def stem(stem_width=32):
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, None, 3])
    X = keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(inputs)
    X = keras.layers.Conv2D(stem_width, kernel_size = 3, strides = 2, activation='relu')(X)
    X = keras.layers.Lambda(print_tensor_shape)(X)
    return keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=X) 

inputs = tf.zeros([32,512,512,3])
out = stem()(inputs)
```